# Como criar uma matriz em python

Tags: python, matriz

Quero criar uma matriz em que o usuário especifica o número de linhas e o número de colunas.
Inicialmente foi dada uma matriz vazia: matriz = []
Os códigos devem partir daí
o código abaixo foi a minha tentativa:

```
def gerar_matriz (n_linhas, n_colunas):
        ''' 
          (int,int) -> matrix
        '''
        matriz = []
        matriz.append(" ")
        matriz.append([" "]*num_linhas)

        i = 0
        while i < len(matriz):
            matriz[i].append(" ")
            i += 1


        return matriz
```

Há uma função main que irá chamar essa função, porém, por enquanto, a minha dúvida é apenas montar essa matriz.

Comment: Ok, tem como você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o que você tentou fazer? Para formatar corretamente o código basta copiá-lo no editor da pergunta, selecioná-lo e pressionar o atalho `Ctrl+K`. Como é um membro recente na comunidade, recomendo que faça o [tour] para entender o básico de como o site funciona.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/462627/impress%c3%a3o-de-matrizes-em-python/462655#462655).

Answer (score 9):

Python não tem, apesar de ter vários tipos nativos, um tipo "matriz" nem nativo, nem na sua biblioteca padrão.

## numpy

Para qualquer trabalho sério envolvendo matrizes (isso é: você tem um problema que envolve matrizes "do mundo real") o ideal é instalar um módulo separado que tenha não só as matrizes, mas código de alta performance para operações nos elementos e entre as matrizes. A mais famosa para isso é de longe o [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Ele é instalado automaticamente nas distribuições científicas de Python como Anaconda e outras.

Com o numpy instalado, você tem uma série de ferramentas para criar matrizes - umas das mais práticas é o `np.zeros` para o qual você passa apenas os tamanhos desejados em cada dimensão e os tipos de dados:

```
In [2]: np.zeros((4,4), dtype=np.float64)
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

E uma coisa legal dessas matrizes é que elas são objetos que fazem uso dos métodos que usam índices num objeto (isso é, os métodos da classe que são chamados quando usamos colchetes depois do objeto) - e usam tuplas nos índices para endereçar os elementos - então `a[0,0]`  vai endereçar o elemento na linha zero, coluna zero da matriz "a". Mais ainda, ele suporta o uso de "slices" do Python nesses índices também, então dá para fazer isso:

```
In [3]: a = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.float64)

In [4]: a[1:4, 1:4] = 1

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

E esssas matrizes já funcionam muita bem com toda uma série de operações definidas para matrizes em matemática - não são apenas "arrays" de objetos burras - você pode somá-las umas com outras, ou realizar qualquer outra operação. Na verdade, o projeto numpy e seu tratamento de matrizes é tão importante para o Python que durante o desenvolvimento da versão 3.5 eles solicitaram que um novo operador fosse acrescentado à linguagem - o `@` que é usado para multilplicação de matrizes.  (Ele não é usado no Python normal - qualquer objeto pode implementar o método `__matmul__` e fazer algo com o operador `@` - mas ele foi criado por solicitação do pessoal do numpy.

```
In [6]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], dtype=np.float)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])

In [8]: b = np.array([2,2,2])

In [10]: a@b
Out[10]: array([ 12.,  30.,  48.])
```

Agora às vezes para projetos muito curtos, ou para fins didáticos, você pode querer criar seus próprios "arrays multidimensionais" - e aí você pode criar listas onde cada elemento é uma lista - com alguns cuidados -
ou - um pouco melhor, implementar sua própria classe que trata os índices de forma parecida com o numpy - ou mesmo usar um dicionário diretamente.

**atualização**: Acabei de descobrir o projeto [tinynumpy](https://github.com/wadetb/tinynumpy): ele tem as mesmas facilidades que as matrizes numpy para coisas simples, mas sua instalação é muito menor e ele é em Python puro:  pode valer a pena em ambientes com restrições à instalação de arquivos binários ou com limitação de espaço em disco.

## listas de listas

Basta usar código Python padrão para criar várias listas dentro de uma lista inicial, e endereçar cada elemento com colchetes seguidos:

```
In [17]: m = []

In [18]: for y in range(4):
    ...:     linha = []
    ...:     for x in range(4):
    ...:         linha.append(0)
    ...:     m.append(linha)
    ...:     

In [19]: m
Out[19]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [20]: m[0][0] = 5

In [21]: m
Out[21]: [[5, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Ou numa única linha:

```
In [22]: n = [[0] * 4 for i in range(4)]

In [23]: n
Out[23]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

E tomando alguns cuidados - por exemplo, se eu multiplico um mesmo objeto "lista" na tentativa de obter várias linhas da matriz, eu na verdade vou ter cópias da mesma linha inicial em todas as linhas, e muitos bugs:

```
In [25]: o = [[0] * 4] * 4 

In [26]: o
Out[26]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [27]: o[0][0] = 1

In [28]: o
Out[28]: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Essa forma é a mais "simples" de criar uma matriz em Python, como está nas outras respostas, mas a que vai dar mais trabalho: as matrizes desse tipo não usufruem em nada das capacidades de orientação a objeto - cada menor operação desejada tem que ser feita endereçando cada elemento da matriz com código externo que usa os dois conjuntos de colchetes.

## dict

Você pode usar simples dicionários em Python como matrizes. Uma vez que tuplas podem ser usadas dentro dos colchetes *e* podem ser chaves do dicionário, você só precisa de um "defaultdict" que retorne o valor inicial para cada elemento que ainda não foi usado  - e, com um mínimo de sofisticação, verifica os limites da matriz.

Dicionários normais tem o método `.setdefault` que pode ser usado no lugar dos colchetes para prover o valor inicial. É legal por que você não precisa construir um objeto especial - mas é ruim por que não vai funcionar com a sintaxe de colchetes para leitura:

```
In [29]: m = dict()

In [30]: m.setdefault((0,0), 0)
Out[30]: 0

In [31]: m[0,0] = 1

In [32]: m.setdefault((0,0), 0)
Out[32]: 1

In [33]: m.setdefault((4,4), 0)
Out[33]: 0
```

## dict personalizado

Agora, o projeto de classe de dicionários prevê que subclassses possam ter o método `__missing__` que seria chamado para automaticamente para um índice não existente.

```
class M(dict):
    def __init__(self, dimensions, default=0):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.default = default

    def _convert(self, index):
        if not hasattr(self, '__len__'):
            raise IndexError('Use a sequence as index for matrices')
        if len(index) != len(self.dimensions):
            raise IndexError("Incorrect index dimentsions")
        for d, i in zip(self.dimensions, index):
            if i < 0 or i >= d:
                raise IndexError("Index out of range")
        return tuple(index)

    def __missing__(self, index):
        index = self._convert(index)
        return self.get(tuple(index), self.default)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        index = self._convert(index)
        return super().__setitem__(index, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        if len(self.dimensions) == 2:
            result = "[{}]".format("\n".join(", ".join(str(self[i, j]) for j in range(self.dimensions[1])) for i in range(self.dimensions[0])))
        else:
            result = "<matrix {} >".format(super().__repr__())
        return result
```

## classe personalizada

Ou, por fim, crie sua própria classe que implemente os métodos `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` e `__delitem__`  para ter um tipo de matriz completamente sob seu controle - eu costumo criar uma classes dessas para manter representações em memória do que está na tela de jogos simples no estilo de snake, tetris,  "candycrush saga", por exemplo.

Answer (score 4):

Se a intenção é apenas criar uma matriz da seguinte forma:

```
[" ", " ", " ", ..., " "]
[" ", " ", " ", ..., " "]
[" ", " ", " ", ..., " "]
[ ...      ...       ...]
[" ", " ", " ", ..., " "]
```

Basta você fazer:

```
return [[" "]*n_colunas for _ in range(n_linhas)]
```

Desta forma:

```
def gerar_matriz (n_linhas, n_colunas):
    return [[" "]*n_colunas for _ in range(n_linhas)]
```

Exemplo:

```
>>> print(gerar_matriz(2, 3))
[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

O código é o equivalente a:

```
def gerar_matriz (n_linhas, n_colunas):
    matriz = []

    for _ in range(n_linhas):
        matriz.append( [" "] * n_colunas )

    return matriz
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NVX9Od)

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz utilizando valores aleatórios, mas no lugar do `random` na variável `n` você pode utilizar `input()` para defini-los.

```
import random
def matriz(n_linhas, n_colunas):
    matriz = [] # Matriz
    linha = [] # Linha

    while len(matriz) != n_linhas: # Quando o número de elementos da matriz(linhas) forem diferentes da quantidade máxima definida pelo usuário, ele ficará rodando.
        n = random.randint(0,99) # Utilizei random para adicionar os valores
        linha.append(n) # Adiciono n à linha

        if len(linha) == n_colunas: # Se a quantidade de elementos for igual à quantidade de colunas definida pelo usuário :
            matriz.append(linha) # Adiciono a linha à matriz
            linha = [] # E zero a "linha" para adicionar outra à matriz
    return matriz # Retorno a mesma


print(matriz(5,4))
```

**Um exemplo de saída:**

```
>>> [[21, 4, 94, 23], [72, 56, 98, 76], [32, 39, 97, 71], [60, 6, 65, 20], [88, 56, 81, 29]]
```