# Impressão de Matrizes em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matriz

Estou inciando em python e preciso resolver vários exercícios de matriz em Python, mas não consigo fazer a impressão correta. Entendendo a Logica deste exercício eu consigo resolver os outros tranquilo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? O código é este:

```
A = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        A.append(input('Informe um valor para o vetor A: '))
print(A)
```

No caso quando digito por exemplo 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 o programa imprime: `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`

Eu preciso que o programa imprima desta forma: `[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que sua lista é unidimensional e você está adicionando os valores diretamente à ela. O que você deve fazer, é criar duas listas dentro dessa sua lista principal e ir adicionando os valores através dos índices de linha.

```
matriz = [[],[],[]]
    
for y in range(len(matriz)):
    for i in range(3):
        matriz[y].append(input("Informe um valor para o vetor A: "))

print(matriz) # [[x, y, z, ...], [x, y, z, ...], [x, y, z, ...]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Para você trabalhar com matrizes você deve levar em consideração o número de `linhas` e de  `colunas` da referida matriz.

Neste caso você terá de especificar o `número de linhas` e também o `número de colunas`.

Para você criar uma matriz com um número qualquer de linhas e colunas, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Este programa insere elementos em uma matriz, exibe a matriz, exibe o tamanho da
# matriz e diz se ela é ou não uma matriz quadrada.

# Capturando e tratando o número de linhas da matriz.
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite a quantidade de linhas da matriz: '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')

# Capturando e tratando o número de colunas da matriz:
while True:
    try:
        m = int(input('Digite a quantidade de colunas da matriz: '))
        if m <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')

# Inserindo cada linha na matriz.
matriz = list()
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    # Inserindo os elemntos em cada linha.
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        # Capturando e tratando cada elemento da matriz:
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento da {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        linha.append(valor)
    matriz.append(linha)

# Tomando decisões e exibindo resultados.
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada foi: {matriz}')

if n == m:
    resp = 'matriz quadrada'
else:
    resp = 'matriz não quadrada'

print(f'A ordem da {resp} é: {n} x {m}')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/wwkwyekw-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.