# Como armazenar valores diferentes em uma variável só

Tags: python, variáveis

Queria pegar uma variável e armazenar valores diferentes. No caso, seriam 7 idades, como fazer?

```
cont = 0
anos = 0
for c in range(1, 8):
    cont += 1
    anos = int(input('Em que ano a {} pessoa nasceu? '))
```

Comment: o que quer usar se chama array. Aqui tem algums exemplos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/462627/impress%c3%a3o-de-matrizes-em-python

Comment: intendi, ai no caso consigo armazenar diferentes valores com essa matriz né, sou iniciante nao entendo muito ainda

Comment: exato, e acessa os valores pelo "índice" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisaria criar um `list` para isso. E utilize `.append()` para adicionar valores ao list.

```py
cont = []
for c in range(1,8):
    cont.append(c)
print(c)
```

Comment: Obrigado Augusto :)

Answer (score 2):

Use listas (apesar de ser semelhante ao array de outras linguagens, [a documentação chama de lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)):

```
idades = [] # lista vazia
for i in range(1, 8):
    idades.append(int(input(f'Em que ano a {i}ª pessoa nasceu?')))
```

Repare que não precisa da variável `cont`, use o próprio `i` que está sendo usado pelo `for` (creio que faltou isso no seu *loop*).

Outra opção é criar a lista de uma vez, usando [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
idades = [ int(input(f'Em que ano a {i}ª pessoa nasceu?')) for i in range(1, 8) ]
```

Comment: Intendi, ai por exemplo se eu quiser imprimir na tela ou fazer alguma soma com essas variaveis eu precisaria colocar um numero dentro de colchetes que represente cada pessoa. 
EX: idade[2] 
se eu quiser usar o segundo valor armazenado?

Comment: @GabrieldaSilvaSantos Na verdade os índices começam em zero, então `idades[0]` é o primeiro, `idades[1]` é o segundo, etc. E tem muita coisa que dá pra fazer com listas, sugiro que leia com calma esse tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/

Comment: Obg pelo help. vou dar uma lida e estudar mais sobre. tmj ^-^